# NoMethodError for nil:NilClass, rails

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

Do I have any error in this code?

```
if current_user.cart
        existing_product = current_user.cart.products.find_by(id:@product.id)
    if existing_product
        subq = SubQuantity.where(product_id: @product.id, cart_id: current_user.cart.id)
        sub_quant = params[:quant]
        subq.first.sub_quantity = subq.first.sub_quantity + sub_quant.to_i
    else
        current_user.cart.products << @product
        subq = SubQuantity.create
        sub_quant = params[:quant]
        subq.sub_quantity = sub_quant
        subq.product = @product
        subq.cart = current_user.cart
    end
else
    @cart = Cart.create
    @sub_quantity = SubQuantity.create
    sub_quant = params[:quant]
    @sub_quantity.sub_quantity = sub_quant
    @product.sub_quantities <<  @sub_quantity
    @cart.sub_quantities <<  @sub_quantity
    @cart.products << @product
    @cart.user = current_user
    @cart.save
    @sub_quantity.save
end
redirect_to root_path
```

What I am trying to do is, checking if current_user's cart has any product with id = @product.id then increase its quantity else add product in cart. My code is not working .. I am getting this error
 `undefined method sub_quantity for nil:NilClass` 
at this line, 
`subq.first.sub_quantity = subq.first.sub_quantity + sub_quant.to_i`

Comment: I have edited code pleae have a look now. On first call it works as expected and moves to 1st `else` part and add an new product to cart. On 2nd call it moves to 1st `if` and then again moves to 2nd `if` instead of going to 2nd `else`. So, obviously on new product sub_quantity should be nil. On that point it should go to inner else i.e, if no existed product then moves to else, but it is not moving to else!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this

```
 subq.first.sub_quantity = subq.first.sub_quantity + sub_quant.to_i
```

produces

```
 undefined method sub_quantity for nil:NilClass
```

It simply means that `subq.first` is returning nil.  `nil` has no `sub_quantity` method, which you try to call on it, so you get that error.

`subq` was defined as:

```
  subq = SubQuantity.where(product_id: @product.id, cart_id: current_user.cart.id)
```

So it means that there were no SubQuantity objects (that is, rows in the database) matching your query. If you have an ActiveRecord query which returns no results, then calling `first` on it will return `nil`.  So there existed no SubQuantity that has a `product_id` of `@product.id` and a `cart_id` of `current_user.cart.id`.

Why that is, whether it should be, or how your code should respond to that condition -- depends on what's going on in your app, I couldn't say.

Comment: I have edited cone pleae have a look now. On first call it works as expected and moves to 1st `else` part and add an new product to cart. On 2nd call it moves to 1st `if` and then again moves to 2nd `if` instead of going to 2nd `else`. So, obviously on new product sub_quantity should be nil. On that point it should go to inner else.

Comment: What is it you want me to look at? Just "if you have any error in this code"? No way to say, it depends on what your entire app is doing.

Comment: I think this statement has a problem
`existing_product = current_user.cart.products.find_by(id:@product.id)`

Comment: what sort of problem? What do you want it to do, or think it should be doing? What problem do you think it has, in what cases might it not be doing that?  It looks to me just fine if you want to find a product with a specific id, in the current_user's cart. If the current user's current cart has no such product, it will return nil, which you need to account for. What do you want your software to do in that case?

Comment: I'm afraid you're just going to have to learn to program in order to.... program.  Copying and pasting lines of code from SO will only get you so far. Other SO contributors may give you lines of code to copy and paste, I won't because I don't think it's helpful, and it's boring to me.

Comment: The problem is, after executing `else` condition, code goes back to `if` condition which it should not be doing. How it can be possible?

Comment: I have checked execution line by line.

Comment: yes, that doesn't make any sense, it ought not to be possible. It seems unlikely. Perhaps that method is actually being called more than once, which is why it seems to 'go back', your debugger trips again on the second execution?  Those kinds of nested ifs are messy and difficult to debug, I'd try extracting things to more, shorter, methods, without nested ifs. it will be easier to work with. You also might find it useful to use ActiveRecord's `first_or_create` in this scenario.

Comment: For debugging I am using `binding.pry`, and may be there is something wrong with it. Anyhow, it is showing my code 1st goes into `else` or `if` depending on flow of program then it goes back upward and move to another condition. I don't know why it is happening since I am only calling this function with link_to helper. And I was not saving object after updating it now I am getting all results fine.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
if existing_product
    //find sub_quantity associated with that product.
    subq = SubQuantity.where(product_id: @product.id, cart_id: current_user.cart.id).first
    if subq
      subq.sub_quantity = subq.first.sub_quantity + params[:quant].to_i 
      subq.save
    end
else
    current_user.cart.products << @product
    // Create a SubQuantity with all attributtes
    SubQuantity.create(sub_quantity: params[:quant], product: @product, cart: current_user.cart)
end
```